# Rails - eager load has_many :through with condition on association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say I have an `Item` model and `Category` model with `has_many :through` association:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_items
  has_many :categories, through: category_items
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_items
  has_many :items, through: category_items
end

class CategoryItems < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :items
end
```

now, I want to have a scope on items that will get all items that are in specific status (assume it has status attribute) for specific category. for example: get all items with status "in stock" and which belongs to category with id = 3, something like:
`scope :in_stock_for_category, ->(category) { where(status: SOME_ENUMERATED_VALUE) ....`
i'm missing the last part of the query to limit the result set to the specific category.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have a `category_id` column in your `items` table, you need to join either `category_items` or `cateogeries` in your scope before you can specify a particular category's ID condition.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :in_stock_for_category, -> do |category|
    joins(:category_items).
    where(category_items: {category_id: category.id}).
    where(items: {status: SOME_ENUMERATED_VALUE}).
    group("items.id") # grouping might be unnecessary since you're adding the where condition for the category's id
  end
end
```

That will work. Or if you want to join `categories`, do the following:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :in_stock_for_category, -> do |category|
    joins(:categories).
    where(categories: {id: category.id}).
    where(items: {status: SOME_ENUMERATED_VALUE}).
    group("items.id") # grouping might be unnecessary since you're adding the where condition for the category's id
  end
end
```

If you already have a `category` however, it might be useful to create a `has_many` relationship for a items that have a certain status. Something like the following:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :in_stock_items, -> do
    where(items: {status: SOME_ENUMERATED_VALUE})
  end, through: :category_items, source: :item
end
```

Also, if you have a status scope in `Item` (something like `scope :in_stock, -> { where(status: SOME_ENUMERATED_VALUE) }`), you can most likely change the above `has_many` relationship to the following:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :in_stock_items, -> do
    merge(Item.in_stock) # http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge
  end, through: :category_items, source: :item
end
```

That should tidy things up.

Comment: BTW - is the `group("items.id")` required here? what's the purpose of that?

Comment: After the `joins`, there might be multiple rows that have the same item because an item can have many categories. By grouping the results by `items.id` you ensure that you get one item per row.

Comment: but after the `where` clause it limits only to items for specific category so it shouldn't have multiple items since they are scoped to this category, no? am I missing anything here? thanks again for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had overlooked that. But normally you would add such a `group` method in this scenario. I've update the response accordingly.